# How to avoid coding same code twice in (if, if else) statement, when the code has to run if one is true?

Tags: if-statement, pseudocode

Consider this pseudo code:

```
if(p){
 foo()
 bar1()
}
if else(q){
 foo()
 bar2()
}
```

Is there a way of avoiding writing the call for function foo() twice? I could write:

```
if(p||q){
 foo()
}
...
```

But is that the only solution?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just run foo before you do the conditional check?

Comment: @enhzflep because there may be situations where neither p nor q are true, so foo should not run at all

Comment: @WinnieThePooh calling the same function twice in different situations is not a problem. In fact that's the idea behind modularization. It may be personal opinion, but I like the first way better, because it seems more readable to me. And for your second snippet you will need two additional if to check whether to run bar1 or bar2

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind there is no problem with calling the same function from both if and else, one of the reasons we do function it's reusability and that is proper way to reuse it.

One of the options to avoid calling the same function:

```
if(p||q){
 foo();
 if (p){
   bar1();
 }
 else {
  bar2();
 }
}
```

Also remember that readability of the code is VERY important and although it's opinion based, I think you way is clearer